# What is the difference between these two tensors and why?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, dimensions

What is the difference in dimension or rank between the first two results shown? Why am I able to add those two (matrices/vectors)? This may sound like a naive question but I am trying hard to understand how addition between tensors/matrices work. Thank you. 
(I also wanted to know why I can add the last two results. Aren't they two different sized matrices?)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10])) 
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,784]))
z = tf.matmul(x,W)

Y = tf.Variable([4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0])  

x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,10]))  

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()  

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
    print(session.run(z))
    print(session.run(Y)) 
    print(session.run(x))
```

Result:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[  4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  14.]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any addition, only multiplication.

All you are doing with the `Y` variable is printing out the tensor itself which contains the floating values you specified.

With `z`, you are multiplying these two tensors together. The general formula for the dimensions of the result of multiplication of matrices is MxN * OxP = MxP (M and O are rows, N and P are columns). So for x, you have a 2x784 tensor multiplied by a 784x10 tensor. This (by the general dimension formula) gives you a tensor with dimensions 2x10.

If you meant that you could do addition after the fact with `Y` and `z`, it is because libraries like tensorflow typically apply broadcasting from one tensor to another as long as some dimension matches. So if you did `Y + z` you would get

```
[[  4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  14.] 
 [  4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  14.]]
```

because of the broadcasting being applied to the number of rows in z.

EDIT: I just thought out that you asked for difference in terms of arithmetic x) because of broadcasting, `z - Y` would be

```
[[  -4.   -5.   -6.   -7.   -8.   -9.  -10.  -11.  -12.  -14.] 
 [  -4.   -5.   -6.   -7.   -8.   -9.  -10.  -11.  -12.  -14.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about broadcasting from one tensor to another. That's what I was trying to understand. I made the question a little precise on what I meant by difference between the first two results.